# Enviar URL com variáveis pelo PHP

Tags: php, formulário

Estou tentando enviar uma URL que possui variaveis que ira ser tratada em um outro site.

Tenho o código:

```
<form action="OUTROSITE.COM/default.aspx?q=1136&lang=pt-PT&CheckIn=<?php echo $_REQUEST['dpd1'];?>&CheckOut=<?php $_REQUEST['dpd2'];?>&ad=<?php echo $_REQUEST['electAdults'];?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
```

E o HTML assim:

```
                <input type="text" value="" id="dpd1" readonly placeholder="Check-in"/>
                <input type="text" value="" id="dpd2" readonly placeholder="Check-out" />
                <select id="selectAdults">
                    <option selected><?php echo $lang['BE_ADULTO']; ?></option>
                    <option value="1" >1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>

                <select id="childs">
                    <option selected><?php echo $lang['BE_CRIANCA']; ?></option>
                    <option value="1">0</option>
                    <option value="2">1</option>
                    <option value="3">2</option>
                    <option value="4">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" placeholder="<?php echo $lang['BE_COD_PROMOCIONAL']; ?>"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Quando faço o envio, o link aberto é:

```
OUTROSITE.COM/default.aspx?q=1136&lang=pt-PT&CheckIn=&CheckOut=&ad=&sid
```

As variáveis não acompanham o link, como posso fazer para enviar o link com as variáveis?

Comment: Esqueceu um `echo` em `$_REQUEST['dpd2']`.

Comment: Ola @Thomas corrigi, mas mesma assim nao funciona, a URL vai vazia

Comment: Se `dpd1` e `dpd2` são `readonly` e iniciam sem valor, como os valores dessas variáveis chegam no `$_REQUEST`?

Comment: é um datepicker do foundation http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html, coloquei readonly para o utilizador nao poder alterar.

Comment: Já tentou remover o `readonly`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta isso:

```
<select id="selectAdults" name="selectAdults">

<select id="childs" name="childs">
```

Se não funcionar, podes sempre alterar os `$_REQUEST['dpd1']` para `$_GET['dpd1']` ou `$_POST['dpd1']`

Comment: realmente era isso, faltava os name="". Obrigado